# What directories can be safely moved to the non boot drive

Tags: startup, spotlight, virtual-memory

I have a 100 GB SSD that has filled up.

I moved `/Applications` to a separate (non-SSD) drive using ditto. The system is much slower including booting up. Does the bootup process use executables in `/Applications`?

**Finder** is also slower; Finder is not in `/Applications`.
Spotlight is far slower. Can it be forced to reindex the files?

In short what folder or files can be safely or intelligently moved off the boot drive? And secondly off the boot drive onto a slower drive of the following:

```
/Applications
/Library 
/Users
```

I thought of splitting up /Applications into Mac/System one and downloaded applications.

Is it sensible to move the `/Users` directory onto the external drive in order to separate it from system files and folders?

And finally, is `rsync` or `ditto` any better for moving?

Comment: In current macOS they split OS and user install application directory `/Applications` now. Prior to that, it’s best to not modify system apps there. You likely can move /Users. But eventually 100 gb will just be too small.

Comment: oh. thanks.  what is the name of the current macos user install app directory? is it under the (each) user or is something like `/Etc/Applications` or `/User/Applications` or `/Usr/Applications` following unix.

Comment: You should not mess with /Applications or /Users.  But you can move a user's home directory to another disk. Do the moving with System Settings/Preferences - don't try to move yourself.

Comment: /Applications/ on Ventura is for 3rd party. The /System/Applications/ directory is for system.

I agree with Gilby, it's best to not mess with these.

Comment: You could consider creating a Fusion drive arrangement which allows macOS to determine what should reside on each physical drive. This would require reinstalling macOS.

Comment: What Mac model is this? Is it a desktop or laptop? (I wouldn't make a Fusion drive with an external, which might be a) absent or b) not spun up yet.)

Answer (score 1):

You should never mess with system folders like /Applications or /Users unless you are already a macOS expert and even then prepared for an unusable system!

But you can move the home folders of individual users to another disk. You should not try to do this manually or with utilities like `rsync`.

Before you start anything like this make sure 1) you have good backup and 2) an alternative administrator user. Both to assist in recovering when something goes wrong.

Open `System Settings`, choose Users & Groups. Right click on a user and select 'Advanced Options...'

On Ventura this displays:
[image]

Select "Choose..." below Home Directory and then a location on another disk. Allow macOS to move the home folder.

In your question you refer to using a non-SSD drive. I strongly recommend that you keep all user home directories on an SSD.  Use a non-SSD only for Time Machine or other backup.

Answer (score 1):

The total size of a macOS installation is about 15 Gb. That includes all the Apple apps like Safari, Mail, Finder. (But not stuff from the App Store like Pages, etc.)

While apps that you install can be quite large, I guarantee you that most of the space on your disk is taken up by your documents. Photos, videos, audio, PDFs, and other document files.

Apple makes it easy to move the Photos.app library; and the Music.app library (both in those apps' preferences). If you use Logic Pro, there are settings there to move the sample library to a new location. (Don't know about Garageband.)

There's no reason why documents need to be under your user account. (You can turn on encryption to secure your data.) Just move stuff and keep it well-ordered.

Comment: About > Storage show 'System' as 54.09GB . Mail is 8.64GB. Photos <1GB.  Applications was moved and linked and its fine. Loading apps is slower but understandable given the harddisk. I have Adobe suite which is also a pig in terms of size. Now off the boot drive. What I do not expect is a slow boot -- unless /Applications is used for Finder and,or other system exes. I figured ALL those were in /bin and /sbin but perhaps not.

Comment: @ABoston "System" in Storage covers a wide range of things. There are several Q&As here about how to deal with large data defined as "System".